# How can i create widgets in my drupal page

Tags: drupal, widget

I am using Drupal to develop my website. I want to show the content in widgets in the home page. I don't know where to start to create that kind of widgets. Widgets in the sense similar to iGoogle widgets which can be resizable. Please help me.

Widgets in the sense, I want container in which content can be placed. This container can be resizable, we can minimize that widget. I will place the content using PHP code.
Regards,
Srinath

Comment: You have to be more specific. "Widgets like iGoogle widgets" is extremely broad. Each and every iGoogle widget requires specific domain knowledge, APIs and programming (showing weather is different from searching movies).

Comment: I have updated the question. Please look at it once.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on drupal.stackexchange.com. Because you appear to be looking for a module/config suggestion. If not, then please elaborate about the javascript and HTML structure you have in mind for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer.

But I found HomeBox module in Drupal pretty interesting. In DashBoard module we can create widgets which can be drag and dropped. But it is quite difficult for naive users like me. With this HomeBox module, we can create as many number of HomeBox pages as we wish. It creates widgets similar to iGoogle ones, which we can drag and drop, maximize, collapse, change the colors of the widgets(If color picker module is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Dashboard module](http://drupal.org/project/dashboard).

From the project page:

> The Dashboard module provides users with personalized dashboard pages
>   similar to iGoogle or MyYahoo. Users can add widgets to their pages
>   and arrange them through the use of a drag and drop interface.
>   Administrators can create widgets through the use of blocks and nodes
>   defined within the system.